# How to translate the post/page content of a theme

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, language-translation

I am working on a site in which I have to give the option of 3 languages on the front page.

I searched a lot and was successful in translating the theme using .pot files but it is translating only the default strings of Wordpress.

I want to translate the post/page contents too which we are adding from wp-admin. 
I don't want to do it with any Google translator or sidebar plugin. I want to offer this option in the index page.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [i18n plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/i18n) such as [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I used your plugin but with that we can set one language at a time. I have to give language option at Website(user end).